# TinyOWS failing to connect to postgresql - Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, tinyows

I'm getting the above error on a new and local TinyOWS installation on Centos 6. Postgresql 9.2, PostGIS 2.0.
I can connect to PostGreSQL locally and from my LAN using several other methods (psql, QGIS, PgAdmin). I've fiddled around with pg_hba.conf so it currently looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.0.10/20         md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
```

and /etc/tinyows.xml is like this:

```
<tinyows online_resource="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows"
 schema_dir="/usr/local/share/tinyows/schema/"
     log="/var/log/tinyows.log"
     log_level="15">

<pg host="localhost" user="postgres" password="*****" dbname="tinyows_demo" port="5432"/>

<metadata name="TinyOWS Server"
    title="TinyOWS Server - Demo Service" />

<layer retrievable="1"
 writable="1"
 ns_prefix="tows"
 ns_uri="http://www.tinyows.org/"
     name="world"
     title="World Administrative Boundaries" />

<layer retrievable="1"
 writable="1"
 ns_prefix="tows"
 ns_uri="http://www.tinyows.org/"
     name="france"
     title="French Administrative Sub Boundaries (IGN - GeoFLA Departements)" />

</tinyows>
```

bit puzzled as to why it's using ident

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf file to listen on all IP addresses. Like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

And restart your db, of course:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```